# Open second UIAlertController from first UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

How can we have a second UIAlert open from the first alert?

The first block of code works fine, the alert is displayed. But I want to to be able to call a second alert view that appears if one of the options in the first alert is selected.

In the example below, xcode doesn't like the use of "self" where the second alert is being called, and I'm not sure how to set it up.

The red error with a white exclamation mark is "Use of unresolved identifier 'self'

Any ideas?

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let firstAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "some message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option A", style: .default, handler: alert2() ))
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option B", style: .default, handler: nil))
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option C", style: .default, handler: nil))
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(firstAlert, animated: true)
}

func alert2(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    //Put second alert code here:

    let secondAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "some message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option A", style: .default, handler: nil ))
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option B", style: .default, handler: nil))
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option C", style: .default, handler: nil))
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(alert2, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Is the error on the line `firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: “Option A”, style: .default, handler: alert2() ))` ?

Comment: Good question, yes sorry I didn't say where the error was. The error is highlighted for the line in the second section that has "self.present(alert2, animated: true)"

Comment: Why are you trying to present the function `alert2`? Present the `secondAlert`.

Comment: I've just changed it to secondAlert and the error is still there.

Comment: You had two errors. That fixes the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had two errors,

first one,  you need to present your second alert in UIAlertController name not in UIAlertAction name

```
 self.present(secondAlert, animated: true)
```

not method name `alert2`

```
self.present(alert2, animated: true)
```

second one, you need to call the first alertcontroller UIAlertAction
 completion handler method like **alert2** not **alert2()**

```
 firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option A", style: .default, handler: alert2 ))
```

**full answer**

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let firstAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "some message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option A", style: .default, handler: alert2 ))
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option B", style: .default, handler: nil))
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option C", style: .default, handler: nil))
    firstAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(firstAlert, animated: true)
}

func alert2(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    //Put second alert code here:
    let secondAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "some message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option A", style: .default, handler: nil ))
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option B", style: .default, handler: nil))
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option C", style: .default, handler: nil))
    secondAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(secondAlert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you both. And that made me realise why I was getting the "self" error, it was because I had the function for alert 2 further down outside of the view did appear section. Once I put it back up there that error went away. Thanks!